# Does the map $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}/p^2) \rightarrow \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ split?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$ $\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$The question is the one in the title: for a prime $p$, does the obvious surjection $\pi\colon \SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/p^2) \rightarrow \SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ split?

Actually, I know that the answer is "no" for $p \geq 5$.  The point is that in that case, there is no way to choose a lift $\tilde{E} \in \SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/p^2)$ of an elementary matrix $E \in \SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ such that $\tilde{E}$ has order $p$.  Unfortunately, this is possible for $p=2$ and $p=3$, so those are my primary interests (but I would also be interested in references for the large primes case, since I am sure I am not the first person to notice the above obstruction).

---

EDIT 3: Excluding the most recent answer (which seems to slightly contradict the others, and which I am going through right now), we now have dealt with everything but $\SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/4) \rightarrow \SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ for $n \geq 4$.  I did a brute-force computation with Mathematica, and assuming I didn't make any errors it shows that there indeed does not exist a lift of the upper triangular matrices (and hence $\SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ itself) for $n=4$, even if we allow determinant $-1$.

EDIT 2: The edit below is slightly wrong.  What it proves is that the map $\GL(2,\mathbb{Z}/4) \rightarrow \GL(2,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ splits.  As people noted below, this doesn't seem to hold for $\SL$.

EDIT: Something which I forgot to put in the original version of the question is that this does split for $p=2$ when $n=2$.  Assuming I have done the calculations correctly, a splitting homomorphism $\sigma\colon \SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/2) \rightarrow \SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/4)$ can be defined in the following way.  On the elementary matrix generators for $\SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/2)$, we define $\sigma$ as follows:

$$\sigma\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix}\right)$$
and
$$\sigma\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{matrix}\right).$$

I don't have any deep explanation as to why this works: all I did was perform some linear algebra to find matrices in $\SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/4)$ satisfying the relations in $\SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ between elementary matrices.  There is actually quite a bit of flexibility in this.  More generally, for constants $a,b,c \in 2 \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ you can also take $\sigma$ as follows:

$$\sigma\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 1+a & 1+b \\ 0 & -1+a \end{matrix}\right)$$
and
$$\sigma\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 1+c & 0 \\ 1+b & -1+c \end{matrix}\right).$$

I haven't done the calculation to see if you can also split it for $p=3$ when $n=2$ — I was able to do the above by hand, but I would need to install Mathematica or something to do all the matrix multiplications in a setting where $1 \neq -1$.

Comment: Do you know the answer for $n = 2$?

Comment: @LSpice: I added the answer I know there to the question.

Comment: @LSpice yes it splits for $(n,p)=(2,2),(2,3)$: by Gaschütz' theorem it's enough to do it on $p$-Sylows of the quotient, which are cyclic of order $p$, and indeed split.

Comment: The splitting you give for $p=2$ give matrices with determinant $-1$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Whoops, you're right!  I'll have to go back and see if I can fix this.

Comment: @YCor: Interesting, which theorem of Gaschütz are you thinking of?

Comment: @BasicQuestionBot Essentially copying as in math.ku.dk/~olsson/manus/Gruppe-2009/gruppe2007en_all.pdf, p16: let $p$ be a prime and let $M$ be a normal abelian $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$. Then $M$ has a direct complement in $G$ if (and only if) it has a direct complement in some/any $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Ah, OK, in view of the given observations, for $n=2$ it only splits for $p=3$ (Gaschütz applies precisely iff the elementary matrix $e_{12}(1)$ lifts).

Comment: Regarding: "I don't have any deep explanation as to why this works". $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, which has a $2$-dimensional representation over the integers. Unfortunately, that representation involves matrices with determinant $1$ .

Comment: @YCor: Ah, that's a cool theorem I didn't know about!  I guess it follows from the fact that the the $p$-primary part of group cohomology is supported on a $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: That's a really nice way to think about it, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The map splits if and only if $(n,p)$ is either $(2,3)$ or $(3,2)$. As far as I know, this is a theorem of C.-H. Sah. See Theorem 7 in

*Sah, Chih-Han*, [**Cohomology of split group extensions**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(74)90099-4), J. Algebra 29, 255-302 (1974). [ZBL0277.20071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0277.20071).

Comment: For those having trouble finding it: The paper restarts its numbering within each section. This is Theorem 7 in Section II.

Answer (score 17):

If $p=2$ then it is easy to check that there is no inverse image of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ of order two, so there is no splitting. If $p=3$ then it actually splits all the way to the $3$-adics, as $SL(2,3)$ is a $3$-adic reflection group lifting the natural representation (the binary tetrahedral group, number $4$ in the Shephard-Todd list).

Edit: actually I don't think the $3$-adics are right. You need cube roots of unity, so the lift is to $SL\left(2,{\mathbb Z}\left[\frac{1+i\sqrt {3}}{2}\right]\right)$. But the cube roots of unity exist modulo $9$, which answers the original question.

Edit 2: The $3$-adics do work! See David E. Speyer's comments below.

Comment: It appears from other comments that the check that I claimed was easy, is not so easy for some, so here are the details. If $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1+2a&1+2b\\2c&1+2d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ then modulo four, $A^2$ is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1+2c&2+2a+2d\\0&1+2c\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. So $c$ has to be even, and then the determinant of $A$ (ever modulo four) is $1+2a+2d$. So $a+d$ is even, and the result is that $A^2$ is not the identity modulo four.

Comment: I think something is wrong in your last statement. $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z})$ contains a copy of the quaternion $8$-group, where as $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/2])$ embeds in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. I compute that  $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the unit group of the Hurwitz quaternions, and therefore lifts to $SL_2(R)$ if $R$ splits the quaternions, something which is true for $\mathbb{Z}_3$ but not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, edited.

Comment: This is very informative, thanks!

Comment: It should be emphasised that this answer deals only with the case $n=2$.

Comment: No, $3$-adics really do work. Note that $\sqrt{-2}$ exists $3$-adically. Put $I = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&0 \end{bmatrix}$, $J = \begin{bmatrix} 1&\sqrt{-2} \\ \sqrt{-2}&-1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $K=IJ$. Then $\pm \text{Id}$, $\pm I$, $\pm J$, $\pm K$ and $\tfrac{1}{2}(\pm \text{Id} \pm I \pm J \pm K)$ form a $24$ element group isomorphic to $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$, and the reduction modulo $3$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I am using the quaternionic row of the character table, not the row that contains a cube root of unity. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_special_linear_group:SL(2,3)

Comment: Thanks, David. Yes, that seems to work. I'll edit it again.

Comment: I suppose it's defined over any field where $-1$ is a sum of two squares.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I think you are right: Group #12 on the Shephard-Todd list is isomorphic to $\text{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_3)$ which does lifts all the way to the $3$-adics.

Comment: That's right: If $a^2+b^2=-1$, then put $J = \begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ b&-a \end{bmatrix}$ and keep the rest as before. I probably should have written that in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

- For $n=2$: (as already said in comments) it splits iff $p=3$. Indeed by Gaschütz, this reduces to whether the matrix $e_{12}(1)$ lifts to an element of order $p$. For $p\ge 5$ it doesn't lift at all to an element of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z})$. For $p=2$ it does, but not to a determinant 1 one. For $p=3$, it lifts to the determinant 1 matrix of order 3 $\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 1\\-3 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.
- For $n\ge 3$ and $p=3$: it doesn't split. It it enough in this case to show that the elementary abelian 3-group of order 9 $\langle e_{12},e_{13}\rangle$ doesn't split to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}/p^2\mathbf{Z})$. That is, $e_{12}$ and $e_{13}$ can't lift to commuting elements of order 9:

First, a formula in an associative unital ring with $9=0$ is $(B+3A)^3=B^3+3(B^2A+BAB+AB^2)$. If $B=1+N$ with $N^2=0$, this writes $(1+N+3A)^3=1+3(N+NAN)$.

Now in the matrix algebra, we have $E_{ij}AE_{ij}=A_{ji}E_{ij}$. So taking $N=E_{ij}$, the condition $(1+N+3A)^3=0$ means $A_{ji}=-1$ mod 3. That is, mod 3, $A=-E_{ji}+A'$ with $A'_{ji}=0$.

Now lift $e_{12}$ and $e_{13}$ to elements of order 3 mod 9: these are $u=I+E_{12}-3E_{21}+3U$ and $v=I+E_{13}-3E_{31}+3V$, with $U_{21}=V_{31}=0$ mod 3.

Now express the condition that $u,v$ commute, i.e. $[u,v]:=uv-vu=0$:
$$0=[E_{12}-3E_{21}+3U,E_{13}-3E_{31}+3V]$$
$$=3\big(-[E_{12},E_{31}]-[E_{21},E_{13}]+[E_{12},V]-[U,E_{13}]\big),$$
so, mod 3
$$0=E_{32}-E_{23}+E_{12}V-VE_{12}+UE_{13}-E_{13}U.$$
Taking the $(3,2)$ entry, we get, modulo 3
$$0=1-0+0-(VE_{12})_{32}+0+0-0=1-V_{31}=1,$$
contradiction.

**Edit:**

- for $n=3$, $p=2$ it lifts (see [D. Speyer's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443673/14094)
- for $n=4$, $p=2$: it doesn't lift:

Namely, the Jordan matrix $I+J=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, of order 4 modulo 2, doesn't lift to a determinant 1 matrix of order 4.

This is just a computation: let a lift (mod 4) be $u=\begin{pmatrix}1+2a & 1+2b & 2c & 2d\\ 2e & 1+2f & 1+2g & 2h \\ 2i & 2j & 1+2k & 1+2l\\ m & n & o & 1+2p\end{pmatrix}$.

Then computation yields
$$\det(u)=1+2(a+f+k+p)+2(e+j+o)+2(i+n)+2m;$$
also we have the formula (just using we are in an associative unital ring with $4=0$)
$(1+J+2A)^4=1+J^4+2(J^2+J^3A+J^2AJ+JAJ^2+AJ^3)$.

Here, for $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c & d\\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & l\\ m & n & o & p\end{pmatrix}$ and $J$ as above (so that $J^4=0$, $u=I+J+2A$) we have $$J^3A+J^2AJ+JAJ^2+AJ^3=\begin{pmatrix}m & i+n & e+j+o & a+f+k+p \\ 0 & m & i+n & e+j+o \\ 0 & 0 & m & i+n \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & m\end{pmatrix}$$
the condition that it is equal mod 2 to $J^2$ yields, mod 2, $m=i+n=a+f+k+p=0$, $e+j+o=1$.

But this yields $\det(u)=-1$.

- I haven't yet checked whether such a matrix fails to lift to a matrix of the same order for $n\ge 5$.

Comment: This is very informative, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

According to Theorem 2.5 in https://doi.org/10.1090/mcom/3236 , the only cases when the map $SL(n,p^2)\to SL(n,p)$ splits are
$$
SL(2,Z_9), SL(3, Z_4)
$$
($SL(2,Z_4)$, $SL(4,Z_4)$ are listed in the theorem as having a supplement, but do not have a complement.)

One can find the complements in each case easily with GAP's function `ComplementClassesRepresentatives`.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting.  It looks like the non-complement theorems mostly come from the literature, and the existence of the complement for small groups is a GAP computation.  I wonder if the error in that GAP computation is that it worked with GL_2 rather than SL_2?  Anyway, I'll have to go look at the cited papers to sort out the remaining cases.

Comment: Thank you @SamHopkins, corrected (its also a supplement case)

Comment: The notation $SL(n,p^2)$ normally means $SL_n$ over the field with $p^2$ elements.

Answer (score 6):

$\def\SL{\text{SL}}$For $n=3$, $p=2$, there is a splitting. $\SL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$ is the simple group of order $168$. It has a $3$ dimensional representation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2} \right]$. (See [Elkies, Section 1.1](http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/files/elkies.pdf).) Since $\sqrt{-7}$ exists in the $2$-adics, this representation can be defined over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (and, in particular, over $\mathbb{Z}/2^k \mathbb{Z}$ for any $k$.)

YCor and Dave Benson have already addressed all of the $p=3$ cases, so what remains is $p=2$, $n \geq 4$.

$\text{SL}_4(\mathbb{F}_2)$ does not lift all the way to the $2$-adics: It is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_8$ and, in characteristic $0$, the [smallest nontrivial representation](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_alternating_group:A8) is $7$-dimensional. But I don't know how to figure out whether it lifts to $\SL_4(\mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z})$.

---

For the record, I'll write up the computation that rules out $p \geq 5$. Let $N$ be a matrix with a single $1$ in position $(i, i+1)$. We are looking for solutions to
$$(\text{Id}+N + p X)^p \equiv \text{Id} \bmod p^2.$$
Since $p^2$ and $N^2$ are $0$, the left hand side is just
$$\text{Id} + p N  + p \binom{p}{2} ( NX+XN ) + p \binom{p}{3} NXN.$$
If $p \geq 5$, then $\binom{p}{2} \equiv \binom{p}{3} \equiv 0 \bmod p$, and this just collapses to $\text{Id}+pN$, giving no solutions.

Comment: This is very informative, thanks!